# React - Passing special characters when opening new window

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, window.open

We have a feature in our ReactJs app to open one page/route from another using `window.open(domain.com/myapp/page2?p1=value1&p2=value2, '_blank')`. Recently, we had to migrate to a different authentication service which blocks the request if the URL contains any special characters. In simple, no GET request with special characters is allowed.

Is there a way to just open the target page/route in a new window when your input contains special characters?

Comment: did you try to `encodeURI` your parameters? Will the authentication still fail in that case? If so you can encode the params in base64 (`btoa(paramValue)`) and decode it when you read the params (`atob(base64ParamValue)`).

Comment: encoding using encodeURIComponent() has the same restriction, but your suggestion to encode using btoa() seems to work in my initial testing. I'll keep testing it for the rest. Thanks!